# LINQ correlated subqueries

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

Starting with the next entities definition:

```
Public Class Certificate{
  public  ID as int;
}

Public Class Authority{
  ID int;
  Certificates IEnumerable<Certificate>;
}
```

My function recives 2 collections: `IEnumerable<Certificate>` and `IEnumerable<Authority>`. I need to select the `Authorities` which `Certificates collection` has at least one Certificate in the `IEnumerable<Certificate>` input parameter.

My firt implementation is enumerating the `IEnumerable<Certificate>` and selecting the `Authority` using a `Where(predicate)`.

```
Public IEnumerable<Authority> SelectAuthorities(authList IEnumerable<Authority>, certList IEnumerable<Certificate>){

  foreach (Certificate loadedCert in certList) {
    yield return auth.Where(a => a.Certificados.Any(c1 => c1.IDCert == loadedCert.IDCert));
  }  

}
```

I think there must be a way to avoid the for loop using a more complex linq correlated subquery (I feel it in the "force") but I can't find it.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use double `Any` to *avoid* loop:

```
authList.Where(a => a.Certificados
                     .Any(c1 => certList.Any(c2 => c1.IDCert == c2.IDCert)));
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks. It's very simple. I think I was in programmer's block. :)